# IOS Swift Spotify SDK error

Tags: ios, sdk, spotify

I'm trying to use the Spotify SDK and I followed that link : https://github.com/spotify/SpotifyLogin

But once I try to login I got this error :
2018-08-17 21:58:15.817008+0200 APITest[6501:1384966] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://authorize?response_type=code&utm_source=spotify-sdk&show_dialog=true&redirect_uri=SpotifyTest%3A%2F%2FreturnAfterLogin&client_id=0641c005f84344fabd44864ce3fc2974&nolinks=true&utm_medium=spotifylogin&utm_campaign=spotifylogin&nosignup=true&scope=streaming%20user-library-read" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

And I don't know how to fix that, so if anyone knows about this I'm all hear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the error message returned by the server?

Comment: I'm using Xcode so this error message is written on the debug console I guess